# What does Microsoft refer to when it states "cloning" messages in TPL Dataflow BroadcastBlock<T>?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, clone, tpl-dataflow

I am referring to the following link in MSDN : [Broadcast Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447(v=vs.110).aspx)

It states that messages to linked-to targets are "cloned".

I like to know what type of clone MS is referring to here, a deep clone? How does it exactly affect memory consumption?

Comment: Of course deep clone, have you evidence it is not doing?

Comment: @programtreasures, so with a BroadcastBlock memory consumption will be n times the amount of memory, consumed, compared to instead iterating over linked-to target blocks and manually posting data items to those blocks?

Comment: Is there an option I am overlooking that forces the broadcast block to  pass data item references rather than a data clone?

Comment: @programtreasures That is not how the `BroadcastBlock` works; the clone function is supplied as a lambda during the blocks creation. As such it can be anything that satisfies the signature `Func<T, T>`. The block itself does not dictate what type of copy takes place, i.e. shallow/deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `BroadcastBlock<T>` you define the cloning function and are therefore completly in charge of how it works. If you want to pass by reference then don't do anything to your object in the cloning function:

`new BroadcastBlock<T>(x => x, options)`

If you want a deep copy you have to do this yourself. The `BroadcastBlock` knows nothing about the data it is handling. It only knows that it drops messages when full and invokes ***your*** function when it passes data down the pipeline.

Also, the `BroadcastBlock` allows you to pass null for the `cloningFunction` this effectively lets you pass the data without manipulation.

```
private TOutput CloneItem(TOutput item)
{
    return _cloningFunction != null ?
        _cloningFunction(item) :
        item;
}
```

**[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Blocks/BroadcastBlock.cs)**

**[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-a-task-scheduler-in-a-dataflow-block)**

Comment: Great, will take a look, thanks. I then find the term "clone" in MSDN highly confusing.